# VB.Net Printdialog is not showing available printers

Tags: vb.net, printdialog

There are 3 printers showing when I print from Excel, Outlook etc.
When I call PrintDialog1.ShowDialog() it is only showing the default printer.
How can I show all available printers?
Thank you

Comment: Printer spooler is turned on?

Comment: Yes - other programs (Outlook, Excel etc) display a print dialog with all available printers displayed.

Answer (score 0):

This should get you a list of installed printers, if it they don't show up with this code, it may be that you need to update drivers?

```
    Dim controller As New ServiceController("Spooler")
    If controller.Status = ServiceControllerStatus.Running Then
        'http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vbgeneral/thread/fe615570-ce3e-419b-86fc-7f98aed71c8f
        For Each currentPrinter As String In System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters
            'now add the currentPrinter to a list ...                   
        Next
    End If
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I am very new to vbnet so please advise where I should put this code.
Thanks

Comment: This is a bit of code to see what printers your VB.net application could see. Could you post your code so we can see what you are looking at?

Comment: Code is just PrintDialog1.ShowDialog()  
Just tested this on my home PC and it correctly shows the installed printers.
When run on my office PC it only shows the local printer although there is also CutePDF and a network printer showing in Control Panel/Devices and Printers. 
Stephen

Comment: I expect you will need to unstall drivers to use the network ones at work

Comment: Hi Chris
Finally solved the problem and feeling a little stupid.
The printers were all in the dialog all the time. I was expecting a vertical scroll bar and did not notice the horizontal one.
Thanks for helping.
Stephen

Comment: Haha! I love those moments. Good to hear you have it sorted.